# How to put restrictions in textbox using inputmask in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I have a textbox which has a format using inputmask, I also added maxlength which should be seven numbers. But whenever I try to submit the input with incomplete details, the output would be 00-0_-_ _ _ or whatever the user inputs. How can I add retstrictions like the input limit, input numerics only, input/fill im values using the correct format and prompt an error when the user inputs an incomplete value. And also how can I have it in a javascript format

```js
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("#EWR").inputmask("99-99-999");
  });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="ewr"><b>CARD N (yy-ww-xxx): </b></label>
    <input size= "50" type = "Text" name = "EWR" style= "margin-left: -5px" id="EWR" maxlength="7" required> 
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For digits only you could use :

```
$("#EWR").keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                return false
            }
});
```

Add this right after the label close tag to display a warning :

```
<span id="errmsg"></span>
```